# Movie database relationship

Tags: database, database-design, oracle11g, relationship, rdbms

I'm designing a database that stores movie related information. I'm stuck on a problem and can't seem to know how to solve it.

So I'm creating a database that store movies, and for my movie table these are its attributes

```
-movieID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
-title VARCHAR(10),
-genres genre_varray,
-producers
-director
-cast
```

I'm going to create another tables for producers, cast and director. My problem is for the fields producers and cast I have to insert a list of people and the cast I have to add a role to each actor, I'm not sure how I would do that, I was thinking of using nested table? Another problem is that a person can be either actor, director, producer or all.

What I have so far is

```
supertype person_type - personID, name, sex
subtype actor_type - country
subtype director_type - country
subtype producer_type - company
table of people of type person_type
table of movie_people - profession
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any person can perform one or more roles on a movie, and the roles they perform will be different for different movies.

I would have a table of people, a table of movies, a table of role types (eg:Actor, Director, Producer,etc) , and a table linking all three with fields of (PersonID, MovieID, RoleID)

I would also have a separate table for MovieGenres rather than the array you have detailed.

Answer (score 2):

In total, you need six tables:

```
GENRES
GenreID
GenreName

ROLES
RoleID
RoleName  

PEOPLE
PersonID
PersonName

MOVIES
MovieID
MovieName
MovieYear

CASTLIST
CastID
MovieID
PersonID
RoleID 

MOVIEGENRE
MovieID
GenreID
```

A person can appear in the castlist of a movie in several roles, which is why I have given the table a surrogate id. Otherwise you will need a primary key composed of all three foreign keys (and that assumes that you want to list a person playing three different characters only once - check out Dr Strangelove).

Edited to include the MovieGenre table.

Comment: In this structure, a movie can only have one genre.

Comment: So instead of having a GenreID field in the films table, you define another join table, with MovieId and GenreID as a composite primary key.